# Map to a 2 dimensional vector

Tags: c++

I want to create a C++ map where key is, say, `int` and value is a 2-D vector of `double`:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<vector<double>>> myMap;
```

suppose I filled it and now I would like to update the second vector mapped by each key (for example divide each element by 2). How would I access that vector iteratively?
The "itr->second[0]" syntax in the statement below is obviously wrong. What would be the right syntax for that action?

```
for(std::map<in, vector<vector<double> > > itr = myMap.begin(); itr != myMap.end();++itr)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < itr->second[0].size();++i)
    {
         itr->second[0][i] /= 2;
    }
}
```

thanks,
rubi

Comment: now you've got it almost correct. see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

`itr->second` is a type of `vector<vector<double>>`, so you have 'two levels' of indexes to iterate over before you can divide a cell by a number.

```
for ....
{
    vector<vector<double>>& vv = itr->second;
    for(int i=0; i<vv.size(); ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<vv[i].size(); ++j)
            vv[i][j] /= 2
}
```

did I understand your question correctly?

edit: after you edited your post, the code is almost correct. You have some typos and your iterator type is invalid, please see (the code below compiles at least in mingw)

```
std::map<int,std::vector<std::vector<double> > > myMap;

for(std::map<int, std::vector<std::vector<double> > >::iterator itr = myMap.begin();
    itr != myMap.end();
    ++itr)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < itr->second[0].size();++i)
    {
         itr->second[0][i] /= 2;
    }
}
```

please note the `::iterator` added. It must not be `::const_iterator` as the map is going to be modified

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution but a little bit different

- used a 2d vector to insert values
- copied that vector into the map
- used another 2d vector to copy contents from the map and do the work
- copied the modified vector back to the map

```
map<int,vector<vector<double>>> myMap;
vector<vector<double>>v;
v.push_back({7,8});
v.push_back({6,9,8});
myMap[0]=v;
for(auto i=myMap.begin();i!=myMap.end();i++)
{
   vector<vector<double>>v1=i->second;
   for(int j=0;j<v1.size();j++)
   {
      for(int k=0;k<v1[j].size();k++)v1[j][k]/=2;
   }
   i->second=v1;
}
```

p.s Ik I'm 8yrs late