# How to access the values of a map<string, vector<int>> in C++?

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am working on my version of a genetic algorithm to solve the knapsack problem in C++. I have a map of string to vector like

```cpp
map<string, vector<int>> objects
{
    {"Object 1", {7, 20, 15}},
    {"Object 2", {3, 50, 10}},
    {"Object 3", {5, 80, 12}},
    {"Object 4", {4, 80, 8}},
    {"Object 5", {2, 40, 11}}
};
```

and a vector of vectors

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> population;
```

where I will store information such as

```cpp
population[0] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
population[1] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
population[2] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
...
```

Each vector is called an `individual`, and each element of a given individual indicates the presence (`1`) or the absence (`0`) of the corresponding object. So, for example, the third individual (`population[2]`) has `Object 1`, `Object 3` and `Object 5`.

What I want to do is write a function which will receive an index from `population` and return the sum of the corresponding values from `objects`. In the case of `population[2]` I'd like to have another vector containing `{14, 140, 38}` (`7+5+2, 20+80+40, 15+12+11`).

But I'm struggling to access the values of the `objects` map.

```cpp
map<string, vector<int>> objects {/*...*/}

vector<vector<int>> population;

void initializePopulation() {/*...*/}

void getScore(vector<int> individual, vector<int>& sum)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sum.push_back(0);
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(individual[j] == 1)
            {
                sum[i] += ???;
            }
        }
    }

int main()
{
   /*...*/
   initializePopulation();
   vector<int> sum;
   getScore(population[2], sum);

}
```

So, as you can see, I'm not sure how to proceed with `sum[i]`. Any suggestions? I'm not very fluent in C++, so a more detailed answer would be appreciated!

Comment: `objects[x][y]`, note that `objects[x]` actually inserts elements if it can't find an element associated with `x`, if you don't want that behaviour, try `objects.find(x)`

Comment: The question is unclear for me. Are you asking how to access the element of the vector in `objects`? If so, `objects["Object 1"]` returns the first vector and `objects["Object 1"][2]` returns `15`. Are you aware that `std::map` actually is sorted by key. Depending on the key names the order could change.

Comment: The keys are lexicographically ordered. `"Object 10"` comes before `"Object 9"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map to a 2 dimensional vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610747/map-to-a-2-dimensional-vector)

Comment: Yes @ThomasSablik, I know that the keys are in alphabetical order. Now I see how to access the individual values, thank you both! However, I'm not sure how to make the code understand that I am referring to `"Object1"` when `j=0`, `"Object2"` when `j=1` and so on.

Comment: A-ha, I think I should use iterators... I'll think about it

Comment: Here is one way to do it: https://onlinegdb.com/r1NeohBVd

Comment: Do you really need a map for your objects? A simple matrix should be sufficient, once you know the 1st row refers to the 1st object, the 2nd row to the 2nd object and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that with some little linear algebra your problem has an easy solution: indeed, if you store the numerical data related to your objects into a matrix A, then for each `population` vector `p` your desired result is simply *p^T A* (or equivalently, *A^T p*) where *^T* denotes the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of a matrix or of a vector.

If you are not planning to employ any linear algebra library, you could implement the [scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) by yourself. Down below there is the code implementing the above idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

std::vector<int> SP(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const &M, std::vector<int> const &P){
    
    std::vector<int> sums(3,0);

    // perform p^T * A operation
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
            sums[j] += M[i][j] * P[i];

    return sums;
}
int main(){
    
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> objects {
    {"Object 1", {7, 20, 15}},
    {"Object 2", {3, 50, 10}},
    {"Object 3", {5, 80, 12}},
    {"Object 4", {4, 80, 8}},
    {"Object 5", {2, 40, 11}}
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> population(3);
    population[0] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
    population[1] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    population[2] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1};


    std::vector<std::vector<int>> A;
    // Extract the numerical data from the map 
    for (auto const& [key, val] : objects)
        A.push_back(val);

    // vector in which the desired values are stored for the 3rd element of the population 
    std::vector<int> s = SP(A,population[2]);

    // Just for checking
    for (int it=0; it<s.size(); it++)
        std::cout << s[it] << std::endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not at all! I actually find it a very simple and elegant solution. Is there any library to transpose a matrix? I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Additionally, my compiler throws an error regarding identifiers for `key` and `val` in your code, how can I fix this?

Comment: @LucasVieira I think that [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is one good option: you can give it a try, if you have time! For the compiler error, you should add -std=c++17 option.

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you! Can I keep this config for all my projects or are there any cases where a previous version is necessary?

Comment: @LucasVieira Glad to help! Do you mean the -std=c++17 option? To be honest, it depends on the code, but I think that you can maintain that option. In case you need to check if there is any problem with this option, you can have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/17).

Answer (score 3):

For both vector of vectors as well as a map, you can use for each loop!
When your map is filled with value

```
for(auto x: objects){
    cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second<<endl;
}
```

This will print key-value pairs in a map with space in between!

In this problem you'll have to iterate values (i.e. the second)  in map too!

```
{"Object 1", {7, 20, 15}}
{"Object 2", {3, 50, 10}}
{"Object 3", {5, 80, 12}}
{"Object 4", {4, 80, 8}}}
{"Object 5", {2, 40, 11}}
```

For something like this the following code should work:

```
for(auto x: objects){
    cout<<x.first<<" ";
    for(auto y: x.second){
        cout<<y<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

For vector of vectors, you can use the same concept!

Try renaming `Object 1, Object 2, ....` to just `1,2, ....`
This will allow you to access values in map by using j from your for loop!

Comment: Thanks for the insight into the iterations! However, `"Object n#"` is a generic name, and I'd like to replace it with, say `"Book"` and other things. So I'd prefer to somehow keep track of this in the map.

Answer (score 3):

For a more simplified version consider this prototype instead, since you are using words like population and genetic, I assume your data to be humungous, so you are better off using **const reference** while passing data around (const&, they won't be copied and will become read-only). global variable is a bad idea in general.

```
void getScore(map<string, vector<int>> const& objects, vector<int> const& individual, vector<int>& sum)
{
    // iterate over each object for the individual
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
            // are you sure you want sum as {14, 140, 38} (7+5+2, 20+80+40, 15+12+11) 
            // not {14,0, 140,0, 38} (7+5+2, 0, 20+80+40, 0, 15+12+11)
            // use else part for later
            if(individual[i] == 1)
            {
                // compute sum for each object
                // retrieve object vector
                auto it = objects.find("KEY"); // KEY generation discussed later
                if(it!=objects.end()){ // validate key :::: important
                  vector<int> ob = objects["KEY"];      //it->second
                  sum.push_back(std::accumulate(ob.begin(),ob.end(),0) ); //  https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/
                }
            } /*else {
                sum.push_back(0);
            }*/
        }
    }
```

KEY generation:

1). generating "Object 1" :

```
string key = "Object " + to_string(i+1)
auto it = objects.find(key);
```

2). suggested :
use integers as key
or
go with an enum like

```
enum ObjList{
    OBJECT_1,
    OBJECT_2,
    OBJECT_3
}
auto it = objects.find(i); //mind your indexes
```

hope it helps, happy coding XD

Comment: Interesting, thanks! However I will substitute `"Objectn#"` with a more specific name without a number, like "Book", so I'd like not to lose the reference to it.